# cant change html element's opacity more than one time

Tags: javascript, css, opacity

I want my `<div>` to slowly become visible!

this is my code:

```
var Thread = {
    sleep: function(ms) {
        var start = Date.now();

        while (true) {
            var clock = (Date.now() - start);
            if (clock >= ms) break;
        }

    }
};



function anime()
{

    var elem = document.getElementById('tagd');


    document.getElementById('tagd').style.opacity += 0.4;
    console.log(document.getElementById('tagd').style.opacity);

    Thread.sleep(1000);

    document.getElementById('tagd').innerHTML ="<h1>Sometext</h1>";
    console.log("do");
function frame()
    {
            num = 0.1;
            elem.style.opacity += num;

    }


}
```

it works, but when I change it to:

```
var Thread = {
    sleep: function(ms) {
        var start = Date.now();

        while (true) {
            var clock = (Date.now() - start);
            if (clock >= ms) break;
        }

    }
};



function anime()
{

    var elem = document.getElementById('tagd');


    document.getElementById('tagd').style.opacity += 0.4;
    console.log(document.getElementById('tagd').style.opacity);

    Thread.sleep(1000);



document.getElementById('tagd').style.opacity += 0.4;
        console.log(document.getElementById('tagd').style.opacity);


function frame()
    {
            num = 0.1;
            elem.style.opacity += num;

    }


}
```

or with `setInterval` second time `opacity` doesn't change!
seams, i cant change the opacity more than once..

html/css code below:

```
<html>

<style>
#tagd{
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
background: darkred;
opacity: 0;
}
</style>

<head>
<script src="test.js"></script>
</head>


<body>

<input type="button" onclick="anime()">

<div id="tagd"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [CSS transitions](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) instead of JS.
Make two CSS classes and change them using JS.

For example. CSS:

```
#tagd {
    opacity: 0;
}


.visible {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 1!important;
}
```

JS:

```
function anime() {
    var element = document.getElementById("tagd");
    element.classList.toggle("visible");
}
```

Comment: Really tnx bro; this what I need